# How to load CSS file for a field in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have a custom admin config field type in Magento and I would like to load up a CSS file for that config field(also javascript too).

The field class:

```
class Company_Module_Block_Configure extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{

    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        // I would like to load the CSS and Javascripts files to the head.
        return "Here comes the field output";
    }
}
```

I have tried this, but no luck. Maybe the head rendered sooner:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addCss('My css url...');
```

Or somehow I should Observe some kind of "before_body_end" event. Is it possible?

### Update #1:

I have started to go through the before_body_end event:

Config.xml

```
<config>
   <global>
       <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <test>
                        <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>test</method>
                    </test>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And the observed method looks like this:

```
public function test($block){
    if($block->getEvent ()->getBlock()->getNameInLayout() == 'before_body_end'){

    }
}
```